# Link with brackets and special characters in Jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, liquid

I'm trying to write a hyperlink in jekyll, with this link in particular:

> https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN600494829_0002?tify={%22pages%22:[46],%22view%22:%22info%22}

The problem is that it gives a liquid syntax error because of the {% part, it thinks that it's a block when it's just part of the link. I'm new to jekyll, and I've tried to look for an answer but I didn't find much. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to escape characters using  a backslash (\\) ?

Comment: @Christian I don't know if I interpreted that correctly, but writing a backslash just before the brackets or the percentage signs didn't work, the backslash was treated as any other character. But trying that I realized "%22" was a way of writing a double quote mark ", so I make the substitution and it worked!, so thanks for the comment.

Comment: So, you used partial URL encoding, which are the special characters, can you post the final URL you used in Jekyll?

Comment: @Christian Well it was the page own encoding, that's why it didn't cross my mind to check what it was doing. The final URL that works was 

"https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN600494829_0002?tify={"pages":[46],%22view%22:%22info%22}"

You can notice that I didn't even change the rest of percentages, as the only problematic one was the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the update, glad you got it working.